# Importing non-geocoded jpeg into active window of ArcMap Data frame?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, georeferencing, data-frame, jpeg-2000

Currently when we draw a new subdivision into our GIS, we snip a .jpeg of the platted subdivision and add it to ArcMap. The un-referenced jpeg is simply dropped out in the middle of nowhere and we have to go retrieve it using the 'Georeferencing' tool. We then georeference the corners of the platted map into our GIS and so on and so forth, we draw the map.

For efficiency sake, is there a way to import a non-gocoded jpeg or raster image into the immediate active window of the data frame? It would greatly speed up our efforts if these files could be dropped somewhere remotely close to where their final geocoded location would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click "Fit to Display" in the Georeferencing menu, the un-georeferenced Image will be moved to the current window location making it much easier to georeference.